# UICollectionViewCell populate with wrong data

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uistackview

I have simple UICollectionViewCell that contains one product. My product have image(UIImageView), name(UILabel), description(UILabel), price(UILabel), rating(UIStackView) shown with 0 to 5 stars and buy button.

I fetch my products from JSON and save it to Array of products.

After app launch my UICollectionView populate with no problems. I use:

```
    var product: Product? {
        didSet {
            populateProduct()
        }
    }
```

to populate data in Cell..

```
    private func populateProduct() {
        guard let product = product else { return }
        let viewModel = ProductViewModel(product: product)
        
        productImageView.loadImage(image: product.imageString)
        productBrand.text = product.brand
        productName.text = product.name
        productDescription.text = product.description
        productPrice.text = viewModel.price
        
        if productRating.arrangedSubviews.count != 5 { // Check if there is rating already
            for star in 1...5 {
                let stars = product.score
                if stars != 0 { // Doesn't show rating if there is none
                    var starImage = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "star-pink"))
                    if star > stars {
                        starImage = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "star-grey"))
                    }
                    starImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
                    productRating.addArrangedSubview(starImage)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Problem is when I scroll collection view and some of my cells are dequed and reused. It doesn't happen every time, but often happens, that my cells swaps a data of products. Specifically the rating and the picture - so for example my first product have his own data, but rating of second product.

I think I fixed the image problem by this code in Cell:

```
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        productImageView.image = nil
    }
```

But I don't found how to reload `arrangedSubviews` in rating StackView or reload whole UIStackView same as just image in UIImageView. Or is there another solution to avoid it?

CellForItemAt

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! ProductCell
        cell.product = products[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
```

And why cells swaps just ratingView?

Comment: show your collectionView method `cellForItem`

Comment: @jawadAli added to the question

Comment: For the cell, you check if the (reused) cell has already 5 stars (grey/pink), but don't check the values of theses star (how many pink one? how many grey ones?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove all subview from `stackView`

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        productImageView.image = nil

       _ = productRating.arrangedSubviews.map { $0.removeFromSuperview() }

 // or

           productRating.arrangedSubviews.forEach { subview in
                
                subview.removeFromSuperview()
            } 
    }
```

Comment: Works! Thank you. But I get `Result of call to 'map' is unused` - why?

Comment: `_ =  productRating.arrangedSubviews.map { $0.removeFromSuperview() }` you can do it like this